# UICollectionView Refresh Issue

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Using `UICollectionView` I add a `Label` to a cell as a `subView` with the scroll direction set to horizontal. Inside the `Label` I add a button whose background is an image. For some odd reason if I scroll the view in one direction and then come back the buttons image seems to either have left remnants to the right of the button. Either that or their is another button slightly shifted to the right under the initial buttons. I have realized the more I played around with the buttons the further right they shift. Any assistance would be appreciated

The issue does not seem to occur if the label is shorter

[image]

```
 var padding = String(count: 2, repeatedValue: (" " as Character))

    let newLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectZero)
    newLabel.autoresizingMask =  .FlexibleHeight
    newLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 56/255, green: 143/255, blue: 212/255, alpha: 1)
    newLabel.text = "\(padding)\(title)\(padding)"
    newLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    let fontName: CFStringRef = "Superclarendon-Regular"
    newLabel.font = CTFontCreateWithName(fontName, 15, nil)
    newLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    newLabel.clipsToBounds = true
    newLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 4
    //Fit TO Text
    newLabel.numberOfLines = 1
    newLabel.sizeToFit()
    //Add Button
    if let image = UIImage(named: "Nav_Button_X"){//?//.CGImage
        let button = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as! UIButton
        var imageWidth = image.size.width
        var imageHeight = image.size.height
        //Resize label for button
        var oldLabelFrame = newLabel.frame
        var buttonHeight = self.frame.height - self.sectionInsets.top - self.sectionInsets.bottom
        var buttonWidth = newLabel.frame.width + imageWidth
        //newLabel.frame = CGRect(x: oldLabelFrame.origin.x, y: oldLabelFrame.origin.y, width: oldLabelFrame.width, height: bh)
        newLabel.frame.size = CGSize(width: buttonWidth, height: buttonHeight)

        button.frame = CGRectMake(newLabel.frame.width - imageWidth, 0, imageWidth, newLabel.frame.height)
        button.setBackgroundImage(image, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        newLabel.addSubview(button)
    }
    return newLabel
}
```

**EDIT**:

I have tried recreating the view using only a button and NSMutableAttributedString for styling, which may or may not be a better solution *shrugs*, and the issue persists so it may not be an issue of how I construct the button. Are there suggestions?

I subclass and set up the UICollectionView like so

```
    let flowLayout:UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout();
    flowLayout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.Horizontal

    super.init(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), collectionViewLayout: flowLayout);

    self.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier);

    self.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.bounces = true
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    self.scrollEnabled = true
    self.delegate = self;
    self.dataSource = self;
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor();
```

and

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

```
let cell:UICollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UICollectionViewCell;
cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor();
let cellItem = subCategories[indexPath.row]
cell.contentView.addSubview(cellItem)

// Configure the cell
return cell
}
```

Another interesting trait is that I removed the button from odd numbered labels and found that when I perform the action to get the issue the buttons appear on all of the labels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like your cells are being reused and they show views from old cells.

When you call `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier`, the method returns a cell that is not visible anymore in the UICollectionView, but it doesn't clear it's content.

Let's say you have cells A, B and C visible, you add subviews to all of them (with `cell.contentView.addSubview(cellItem)`). When you scroll until cell A isn't visible anymore, and you call `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier` to get a new cell (call it D), you'll reuse cell A, so it'll have the subviews you added before to cell A, and the subviews you add now to cell D.

To get rid of this, you have two options:

1. If you're using a custom `UICollectionViewCell`, you should override `prepareForReuse` method. There you should remove all contentView's subviews.
2. If you're using a `UICollectionViewCell`, you should remove all contentView's subviews before calling `cell.contentView.addSubview(cellItem)`

If you want to see if you're adding the button multiple times to reused cells, you can reproduce the issue and use the View Hierarchy inspector:

[image]

I created a small project to illustrate the issue of "dirty" cells: https://github.com/lucaslt89/DirtyUICollectionViewCellsExample

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I created the view hierarchy in the `init` method of the cell.

When scrolling slowly, the cells along with the multiline labels would appear perfectly. However, when scrolling too quickly, labels would have the size of the reused cell's label, thus appearing very bad.

I was setting `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` correctly, but nevertheless the cells would have issues on fast scrolling.

My problem was solved by calling `setNeedsLayout` inside `prepareForReuse`:

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    setNeedsLayout()
    super.prepareForReuse()
}
```